# Suggest Tag 'external-object'

Tags: discussion, tags

I suggest the tag `external-object` would be a useful addition to this knowledge repository.

Answer (score 2):

The [external-objects](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/external-objects) (plural) tag exist and is considered a synonym of [lightning-connect](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lightning-connect) at this time. Though I can see why that may be too general and separate tags could have a purpose.